# iPhone - GLKit Draw Method too slow on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, glkit

**Solution:** I set up all the textures once before, rather than every frame, and I did the same for the GLKBaseEffect and that fixed it! :D

---

Ok I seriously need help with this problem as it is causing a lot of issues.

I am creating a game engine, so basically its physics rendering and game loops etc.
Whenever I run this app on the simulator, it runs smoothly and fast and it is basically fine.
However, when I deploy the app on my iPhone 3GS (Jailbroken to use it for development) it runs very slowly. The entity move incredibly slowly and it has quite jerky motion, not smooth. It sort of jumps forward.

I am using a GLKViewController to draw and update the game.

I have found that the smoothness  improves if I reduce the entities on screen and if it is not animating their images, but it is still very slow moving an entity, and that cannot be the solution because I can't have a game with just one object in it…

Does anyone know how I can make it run smoothly and at the same speed on my iPhone?
Please Help, I have been trying to fix this for the past two days (literally the best part of 48 hours)

vvv ALL THE CODE vvv

This is the custom GLKViewController Class:

```
#import "RWViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface RWViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@end

@implementation RWViewController
@synthesize context = _context;
@synthesize rwEngine;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if(!self.context)
        NSLog(@"Failed To Create ES Context");

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *) self.view;
    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
    view.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true;
    view.context = self.context;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
    rwEngine = [[RWEngine alloc] ignition];
}

#pragma mark - GLKViewDelegate

-(void) glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(104.0/255.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);    
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    [rwEngine draw];
}

- (void)update {
    [rwEngine update];
}

@end
```

This is the rwEngine Class Code:

```
#import "RWEngine.h"

@implementation RWEngine

TestWorld *  world;

-(RWEngine *) ignition
{
    //Game Loop Tick Set to ~60 fps

    world = [[TestWorld alloc] load];
    return self;
}

-(void)update
{
    [[self getActiveWorld] update];
}

-(void)draw
{
    [[self getActiveWorld] draw];
}

-(NSMutableArray *) getWorlds
{

}

-(World *) getActiveWorld
{
    return world;
}

@end
```

The drawing path goes ViewController>Engine>World>Room>Entity

Here is the Entity Draw Method:

```
-(void) draw
{
    CGPoint drawPoint = (self.room == nil) ? self.location : CGPointMake(self.location.x - self.room.viewPoint.x, self.location.y - self.room.viewPoint.y);
    if(isAnimated)
    {
        SpriteInfo * frame = [[self getAnimation] getCurrentFrame];
        [RWImageRenderer renderSprite:frame.imageName position:drawPoint spritePosition:frame.spritePosition spriteDimensions:frame.spriteSize];
    }

    else if(!isAnimated)
    {

        SpriteInfo * spriteInfo = [self getSprite];
        NSString * imageName = spriteInfo.imageName;
        CGSize spriteSize = spriteInfo.spriteSize;
        CGPoint spritePosition = spriteInfo.spritePosition;

        [RWImageRenderer renderSprite:imageName position:drawPoint spritePosition:spritePosition spriteDimensions:spriteSize];
    }
}
```

And this is the RWImageRenderer code:

```
+(void)renderSprite:(NSString *)filePath position:(CGPoint) position spritePosition:(CGPoint)spriteP spriteDimensions:(CGSize)spriteD
{
    [self renderSpriteWithRotation:filePath position:position spritePosition: spriteP spriteDimensions:spriteD rotationOrigin:CGPointMake(0, 0) rotationDegrees:0];
}

+(void)renderSpriteWithRotation:(NSString *)filePath position:(CGPoint) position spritePosition:(CGPoint)spriteP spriteDimensions:(CGSize)spriteD rotationOrigin:(CGPoint) origin rotationDegrees:(int) degrees
{
    NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft, nil];

    NSError * error;
    NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:nil];

    GLKTextureInfo * textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];

    NSInteger spriteWidth, spriteHeight;
    spriteWidth = (spriteD.width == -1 && spriteD.height == -1) ? textureInfo.width : spriteD.width;
    spriteHeight = (spriteD.width == -1 && spriteD.height == -1) ? textureInfo.height : spriteD.height;

    GLKBaseEffect* effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];    
    effect.transform.projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, 480, 320, 0, -1024, 1024);

    if(textureInfo == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Loading image: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    float spriteX = spriteP.x / textureInfo.width;
    float spriteY = spriteP.y / textureInfo.height;
    float textureWidth = ((float)spriteWidth) / textureInfo.width;
    float textureHeight = ((float)spriteHeight) / textureInfo.height;

    VertexQuad quad;

    if(degrees != 0)
    {
        quad.tl.positionVertex = [self rotatePoint:CGPointMake(position.x, position.y) origin:origin angleofRotation:degrees];
        quad.tr.positionVertex = [self rotatePoint:CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y) origin:origin angleofRotation:degrees];
        quad.bl.positionVertex = [self rotatePoint:CGPointMake(position.x, position.y + spriteHeight) origin:origin angleofRotation:degrees];
        quad.br.positionVertex = [self rotatePoint:CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y + spriteHeight) origin:origin angleofRotation:degrees];

        //quad.tr.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y);
        //quad.bl.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y + spriteHeight);
        //quad.br.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y + spriteHeight);
    }
    else if(degrees == 0)
    {
        quad.tl.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y);
        quad.tr.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y);
        quad.bl.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y + spriteHeight);
        quad.br.positionVertex = CGPointMake(position.x+spriteWidth, position.y + spriteHeight);
    }
    quad.tl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(spriteX, 1 - spriteY);
    quad.tr.textureVertex = CGPointMake(spriteX + textureWidth, 1 - spriteY);
    quad.bl.textureVertex = CGPointMake(spriteX, 1 - spriteY - textureHeight);
    quad.br.textureVertex = CGPointMake(spriteX + textureWidth, 1 - spriteY - textureHeight);

    effect.texture2d0.name = textureInfo.name;
    effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

    [effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

    long offset = (long)&quad;
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ImageVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(ImageVertex, positionVertex)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ImageVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(ImageVertex, textureVertex)));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: Not so much of a fix, but you should try it on a iPhone 4 & 5. If they work smoothly, you could just ignore the issue since 3GS is a pretty small slice of the market. Also, it should be noted that the simulator is as powerful as your computer, and has no correlation to the phone processor power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the texture only once, and then use the reference to GLKTextureInfo when drawing. Calling this line for each draw must be killing your performance:

```
GLKTextureInfo * textureInfo = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path         options:options error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped loads. I set up all the textures before, but it was still really slow, so I thought about what else could be called once, not every frame, and I tried the GLKBaseEffect and it worked like a charm, so I am choosing your answer, because you put me in the right mind set :D

Comment: Glad it helped :) I must have missed that in your code, it does make sense to initialize GLKBaseEffect only once too. Although, I would have expected the impact from that to be far less than GLKTextureLoader